# Accessing/Intercepting Nashorn's Global Object Variables

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

This is along the same lines as the question titled ["Capturing Nashorn's Global Variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807683/capturing-nashorns-global-variables). I'm finding it very limiting not being able to intercept the assignment of variables to the global object.

For instance, say I eval the script "a = 10". Perhaps I want to call a listener to notify something that 'a' was added to the scope. The only way I could do this is to investigate the global object after the script is eval'd.

Or say i want to intercept an object being assigned to the global scope and substitute it for another; if it was using `Bindings` I could implement `put`, and delegate off to some other bindings:

```
public Object put(String name, Object value) {
    //put a toStringed version of the object in scope
    return delegate.put(name, value+"");
}
```

This way, when the code 'a=10' is evalled, it would put "10" in scope instead of 10.

It's handy having a `Bindings` interface to implement, but frustrating that I can't provide something like this implementation for the global object. `ScriptObjectMirror` is final, so I can't even overload this and hijack the subsequent call to the internal `ScriptObject`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want to do is to intercept/trap assignments to arbitrary properties on some object. In your case, the global object.

Afaik, this was never really possible without some pretty hacky code indeed. A search for 'observables javascript' might help you with that, but be warned that you'll get into some muddy territory.

If this is meant for testing (as opposed to production code), a `setTimeout` / `setInterval` with some listener that periodically enumerates all properties of the global object and logs a warning if one was added might be good enough for you.

In the future, we'll have the [Javascript Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) standard to help us with this but I seriously doubt it is there yet in Nashorn. It's been a while since I worked with Nashorn but after the initial burst on the scene it has been quiet on the Nashorn front afaict...