# Access variable of ScriptContext using Nashorn JavaScript Engine (Java 8)

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, nashorn

I used the following code with the `Rhino` JavaScript engine in Java:

```
@Test
public void testRhino() throws ScriptException {
    final ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    final ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("rhino");
    final String raw = "I am the raw value injected";
    final ScriptContext ctx = new SimpleScriptContext();
    ctx.setAttribute("raw", raw, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    String script = "var result = 'I am a result';";
    script += "java.lang.System.out.println(raw);";
    script += "'I am a returned value';";

    final Object res = engine.eval(script, ctx);
    System.out.println(ctx.getAttribute("result"));
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

The output of the script (using `Rhino`) is:

```
I am the raw value injected
I am a result
I am a returned value
```

Within the `Nashorn` JavaScript engine, I get no value for the `result`:

```
@Test
public void testNashorn() throws ScriptException {
    final ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    final ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    final String raw = "I am the raw value injected";
    final ScriptContext ctx = new SimpleScriptContext();
    ctx.setAttribute("raw", raw, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    String script = "var result = 'I am a result';";
    script += "java.lang.System.out.println(raw);";
    script += "'I am a returned value';";

    final Object res = engine.eval(script, ctx);
    System.out.println(ctx.getAttribute("result"));
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

returns

```
I am the raw value injected
null
I am a returned value
```

How can I access the value of the `result` variable of the `ScriptContext` using the `nashorn` engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [ScriptEngine.createEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#createBindings--) API to create ENGINE_SCOPE Bindings, it'll work as expected:

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    final ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
    final String raw = "I am the raw value injected";
    final ScriptContext ctx = new SimpleScriptContext();

    // **This is the inserted line**
    ctx.setBindings(engine.createBindings(), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    ctx.setAttribute("raw", raw, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    String script = "var result = 'I am a result';";
    script += "java.lang.System.out.println(raw);";
    script += "'I am a returned value';";

    final Object res = engine.eval(script, ctx);
    System.out.println(ctx.getAttribute("result"));
    System.out.println(res);
 }
}
```

Comment: `NashornScriptEngine#createBindings()` returns either a `new SimpleBindings()`, if global-per-engine is set, or `createGlobalMirror()` if it is not set.  Running with either `-Dnashorn.args=--global-per-engine`, or adding the line `System.setProperty("nashorn.args", "--global-per-engine");` before the engine is created, will both cause `ctx.getAttribute("result")` to again return `null`.  Working around Nashorn's global is one of the biggest pains in embedding Nashorn in a Java application.

Answer (score 3):

Nashorn treats the `Bindings` stored in `ScriptContext` as "read-only".
Any attempt to set a variable stored in a `Bindings` object (or to create a new variable) will result in a new variable being created in `nashorn.global` which shadows the `Bindings` parameter by that name.

You can use the engine to "evaluate" the variable, using this code:

```
System.out.println( engine.eval("result", ctx) );
```

This is, however, quite ugly.  "result" is first compiled into a script, and then that script is evaluated, to return the variable's value.  Fine for testing, but perhaps a little too inefficient for a general solution.

A better, but perhaps more fragile method, is to extract the "nashorn.global" variable, and query it for the desired value.

```
Bindings nashorn_global = (Bindings) ctx.getAttribute("nashorn.global");
System.out.println( nashorn_global.get("result") );
```

See also my hack/answer in [Capturing Nashorn's Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855300/3690024) for automated way of moving `nashorn.global` values back to a `Map<String,Object>` after evaluating a script.

Comment: It is possible create a new Bindings object using ScriptEngine.createBindings API. This creates a Binding that is directly backed by Nashorn's Global instance - which reflects read/writes into JS global scope always.

Comment: @A.Sundararajan  If `-Dnashorn.args=--global-per-engine` is set, then the problem remains even if you use `ScriptEngine.createBindings()`.

Comment: With --globals-per-engine, there is only one underlying JS/Nashorn global object per engine. All ENGINE_SCOPE bindings will share the same underlying Nashorn global instance! As you've observed above, engine.createBindings() in --global-per-engine case would just return a SimpleBindings (not a Bindings backed by a fresh Nashorn Global instance).